Dynamic Theme Support using FullCalendar in React application
I'm working on integrating theme support into my FullCalendar react application using v6.1.11. I want the ability to select different themes dynamically.
As a reference, I've looked at the theme chooser demo provided in the FullCalendar documentation. However, I'm struggling to implement this functionality.
How can I set themeName that is present in the demo as this property does not exist in FullCalendar or a workaround for this feature?
Here's what I've tried so far:
Imported Bootswatch themes' CSS files:
import "bootswatch/dist/[theme]/bootstrap.min.css";
// Note: Replace ^[theme]^ (examples: cerulean, darkly, slate, minty, litera, etc.)

and set the themeSystem property to 'bootstrap5':
<FullCalendar
  plugins={[dayGridPlugin, bootstrap5Plugin]}
  themeSystem='bootstrap5'
/>

While this approach works, the theme is hardcoded (one theme at a time) and not dynamically changeable.

You can use something like calendar.setOption('themeSystem', themeSystem); to set the option dynamically. If you look at the source code of that theme chooser demo (you can use your browser's Developer Tools to inspect it) you can see that's how it's done. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dynamic-options for more info. If you're using React you can refer to https://fullcalendar.io/docs/react for how to get the Calendar API object in order to make the setOption call
